# Issue with Django migration: The field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application was declared with a lazy reference

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I am encountering an issue with Django migration while using the django-oauth-toolkit library in my Django project. The error message states that the field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'apis.customapplicationmodel', but the app 'apis' is not installed.

Here is some information about my project setup:

```
Django version: 4.0.6
django-oauth-toolkit version: 2.2.0
```

Project Structure:

```
accs
cms
apis
    migrations
    models
        __init.py__
        custom_application.py
    static
    templates
    views
    __init.py__
    apps.py
    urls.py
owner
sonline
tnt
```

custom_application.py

```
from django.db import models
from oauth2_provider.models import AbstractApplication

from tnt.models import TntModel


class CustomApplicationModel(AbstractApplication):
    tnt = models.ForeignKey(TntModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta(AbstractApplication.Meta):
        pass
```

settings.py, which is in `sonline` directory

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'cms',
    'accs',
    'tnt',
    'owner',
    'rest_framework',
    'background_task',
    'apis',
    'oauth2_provider',
]

# OAUTH2 settings
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 604800
}

OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'apis.CustomApplicationModel'
```

When I run the following commands, it gives me the below error:

```
(venv) PS D:\s> python .\manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'apis':
  apis\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model CustomApplicationModel
(venv) PS D:\s> python .\manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accs, admin, auth, background_task, cms, contenttypes, oauth2_provider, apis, sessions, tnt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\s\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 236, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 544, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 615, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'apis.customapplicationmodel', but app 'apis' isn't installed.    
The field oauth2_provider.Grant.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'apis.customapplicationmodel', but app 'apis' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.IDToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'apis.customapplicationmodel', but app 'apis' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'apis.customapplicationmodel', but app 'apis' isn't installed.
(venv) PS D:\s>
```

What I am trying to do?:
I need to add an attribute in the `oauth2_provider_application` table, which you can see in `custom_application.py`, I am adding tnt attribute which refers to TntModel.

Can you please help me out here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try in `apis/__init__.py` adding this line:
`default_app_config = 'apis.apps.ApisConfig'` and then `makemigrations and migrate`

also try change `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'apis.models.CustomApplicationModel'` then delete migrations `apis/migrations` and then `makemigrations and migrate`

Comment: @oruchkin I tried what you said. First I added the line `default_app_config = 'apis.apps.ApisConfig'`, and when I tried to migrate, got the same issue as posted in the question.
And with the second change `OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'apis.models.CustomApplicationModel'`, I got error in makemigrations. Error: `ValueError: Invalid model reference 'sanstha_api.models.CustomApplicationModel'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Can you share a repro project on GitHub?